# Azure-DevOps - Git Commit Status

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, continuous-integration

We use Jenkins for Build Automation and Azure DevOps for git repository.

For testing purpose, I manually make job failed on jenkins to push failed status.
Then make normal run, and succeed status pushed to Azure DevOps.
[image]
But as you see on picture, overall commit status remains as failed.

Rest API that I've used is
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/statuses/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

HTTP Post request sample to Azure DevOps server is:

```
{
"state": "failed",
"description": "The build is successful",
"targetUrl": "https://myjenkins-server/job/demo-repo/job/demo-branch/7/",
"context": {
    "name": "build#34",
    "genre": "CI"
}
```

As you see, buildnumber 21 failed, but #22 and #23 is succeeded. And overall status remains failed.
What can be issue for this?
HTTP Api version is api-version=7.0
Azure DevOps cloud based.

Update:
If I re-run Jenkins job after failed status, it creates job and targetUrl changed, because of new job ID, so new Azure DevOps git commit status created.

1. I should not do unique targetURL
   or
2. How to remove previous commit status ?

Answer (score 0):

Please note: the overall status of the repository branch will show as succeeded only if the status of all build pipelines is succeeded.

Comment: Yes, I got it. But for some reason if I re-run Jenkins job if targerUrl has been changed it creates new git status.